# how to check that if a binary tree isComplete() in data structure?

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree

how to check  if a binary tree isComplete() in data structure? 
the leaves nodes have to be filled from left to right without gap

Answer (score 0):

You could have a recursive method that queries the left and right child to see if they have two children each and if they do, returns a true.  Then you just call that method and pass it your root and it'll return either true or false after recursing through each of its children and their children.